# Covert Date Range to Numpy Array as part of Groupby in Pandas

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I have a `Pandas` `dataframe` queried from a database that has three columns. A start date, end date, and a person. The data may not make a lot of sense, but is just a simplified example.

```
    startdate     enddate person
0  2016-01-01  2016-01-02      A
1  2016-01-03  2016-01-03      A
2  2016-01-01  2016-01-01      B
3  2016-01-02  2016-01-02      B
```

Over a given date range, I'd like to know what days are covered by the entries in my `dataframe` for each person. My thought it to create an `numpy` `array` with a length equal to number of days in the range. If that particular day falls in the range, the value of that index in the array is set to 1, otherwise 0. I can then flatten with a `groupby` and `lambda` function.

So given the above dataframe, and a date range of `2016-01-01` to `2016-01-03`, the final result would be:

```
       date_binary
person            
A        [1, 1, 1]
B        [1, 1, 0]
```

I've been able to work out some of the code (the `groupby` part), but am not sure how to go from a date range to an array. So in the full example below, I just hardcoded the transformed dataframe. I suppose, I could have asked a simplier question just around the part with the problem, but I know with `Pandas` there is often a very compact way to do things, so I am posting even the working part.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
# initial dataset
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['2016-01-01', '2016-01-02', 'A'],
                        ['2016-01-03', '2016-01-03', 'A'],
                        ['2016-01-01', '2016-01-01', 'B'],
                        ['2016-01-02', '2016-01-02', 'B']],
                  columns=['startdate', 'enddate', 'person'])

# convert columns to dates
df['startdate']= pd.to_datetime(df['startdate'],  format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['enddate']= pd.to_datetime(df['enddate'],  format='%Y-%m-%d')

# define period for which the matrix should be created
start_date = datetime(month=01, day=1, year=2016)
end_date = datetime(month=1, day=10, year=2016)


######################
# Unsure how to do this 
#####################

# what the dataframe should look like
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[[1, 1, 0], 'A'],
                         [[0, 0, 1], 'A'],
                         [[1, 0, 0], 'B'],
                         [[0, 1, 0], 'B']],
                  columns=['date_binary', 'person'])

# flatten by person
df = df.groupby('person').aggregate(lambda x: tuple(x))

# take the max value
df.date_binary = df.date_binary.apply(lambda x: np.array([max(i) for i in zip(*x)]))

print df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) custom function with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.reindex.html) by your [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) which return `new_index` and `indexer`. Last need replace in `indexer` values `-1` to `0` and another values to `1` by [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
# define period for which the matrix should be created
start_date = datetime(month=1, day=1, year=2016)
end_date = datetime(month=1, day=3, year=2016)

dr = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date) 

def f(x):
    arr = pd.date_range(x.startdate, x.enddate).reindex(dr)[1]
    return pd.Series([np.where(arr == -1, 0, 1)])

df['date_binary'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
df = df[['date_binary', 'person']]
print (df)
  date_binary person
0   [1, 1, 0]      A
1   [0, 0, 1]      A
2   [1, 0, 0]      B
3   [0, 1, 0]      B
```

Comment: thanks this is a nice solution. Can you explain what `np.where(arr == -1, 0, 1)` is doing?

Comment: numpy where is simple if condition is True then 0 else 1. And here indexer return `-1` if value missing - you need `0` and for another values need `1`

Comment: when I print `arr` the first row of the array is `[ 0  1 -1]`. As this corresponds to `['2016-01-01', '2016-01-02', 'A']`, shouldn't it be `[1, 1, -1]` since we have two matches, then a day outside of range? Maybe I don't understand what that code is doing.

Comment: I understand it `-1` means value is missing, if `0`, `1`, `2` it is index of value from first array